# MapBoxGL add GeoJSON circular markers with custom color

Tags: image, addition, mapbox, geojson, marker

I need to add markers to a mapboxgl map using GeoJSON data I get via AJAX. I add the GeoJSON layer this way:

```
    geoJSONSource = new mapboxgl.GeoJSONSource({
        data: geodata
    });

    map.addSource('markers', geoJSONSource);
    map.addLayer({
        "id": "markers",
        "interactive": true,
        "type": "symbol",
        "source": "markers",
        "layout": {
            "icon-image": "{marker-symbol}-15", // stuff in {} gets replaced by the corresponding value
            "icon-allow-overlap": true,
            "icon-size": 1 // size of the icon
        }
    });
```

In the GeoJSON data itself, I set each feature to have the property 'marker-symbol' to 'rocket' in a loop before I add the GeoJSON to the map. However, what I need are small, circular images for each point, not a rocket. I would like to set the points to a small, circular image of one of three colors, depending on data contained in the GeoJSON. I plan to pick the svg image in a loop before I add the GeoJSON to the map.

How do I add a custom icon-image? It seems that even if I type gibberish for the icon-image field, the rocket image from Mapbox's pre-made marker symbols gets loaded. Otherwise, how do I add a custom marker-symbol?

I am using the streets-v8 mapbox style; I tried experimenting with making my own styles to access custom images for markers according to this link:

```
https://www.mapbox.com/help/custom-markers/#use-images-in-mapbox-gl-js
```

But I couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The marker icons are loaded based on the [current sprite sheet](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-style-spec/#sprite) set in the style.

To load a custom icon-image, you need to specify a custom sprite json file in your style.json. Here is the corresponding github discussion with details: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/822

Here is an example of using custom sprites: http://codepen.io/znak/pen/PqOEyV

The map uses a custom style defined in a file called `customstyle.json`:

```
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    center: center,
    zoom: 8,
    style: 'http://www.lenart.pl/assets/codepen/customstyle.json'
});
```

where `customstyle.json` refers to a `customsprite.json`

```
"sprite": "http://www.lenart.pl/assets/codepen/customsprite",
```

`customsprite.json` specifies how to crop the corresponding PNG spritesheet located here:

```
http://www.lenart.pl/assets/codepen/customsprite.png
```

You can also use this utility: https://github.com/mapbox/spritezero-cli to generate the sprite json and the corresponding png spritesheet out of a directory full of SVG files.

Comment: Is there a way to edit the style.json of a style made using mapbox studio? I would like one of the pre-built templates for creating the map and just add an icon sprite to use with markers. I guess another question is: If I use a custom json style file like you mention, will I still be able to easily have a basic mapbox map as base (with roads, borders, etc.) to which I can add my custom sprite for the marker? Or must I provide everything to draw the basic map if I go the customstyle.json way?

Comment: Haven't tried it, but you should be able to duplicate an existing mapbox style and change the sprite reference. Since the style.json refers to the same vector data sources, it should work. If you are using Mapbox Studio you can upload your svgs directly and it will create a spreadsheet for you: https://www.mapbox.com/help/define-sprite/

Comment: I downloaded the style.json of a style I made in mapbox. Then I created the sprite.json and sprite.png of my svg file using that tool you linked as well as changing the sprite variable in the style.json to point to the sprite.json I created using the tool. It worked great, thanks for the detailed answer.

Comment: Great! Happy to hear that my answers were useful!